# External hard drive not showing files in it on Windows 8.1 after a while

Tags: windows-8.1, external-hard-drive, filesystems

I am having a weird problem. The issue is that after some time my hard drive data automatically gets disappear. Even if i unplug the USB cable of external hard drive windows still showing it connected and then after a while it shows disconnected. Then i re-connect this hard drive again and every things works fine means i can see all my files and data in it. But later on this issue occur again and again i am not able to identify which is triggering this issue.

Additional Information:
Hard drive: Seagate backup plus
Operating System: Windows 8.1

Any suggestion will be helpful...

Comment: External drive is dying perhaps. Have you done any disk checks or SMART checks yet?  When is disappears, does it still show up in Windows' Device Manager, and/or in the Disk Management utility?   Does it behave the same way on other computers? Do other external drives work OK with your PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted all my temp and %temp% files and this issue has been resolved. But this i need to do every time after every start of the computer. I don't know specifically which temp file was causing this issue but blindly i deleted all the temporary files and i have's face this issue again.